# Fusiontableslayer using KML Geometry column get correct zoom level and center map

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-fusion-tables

I have a large KML file that I have converted into a Fusion Table. Using the code below I can plot polygons onto a map. What I would like to do now is to get the correct Zoom level so the polygon can fill the map canvas and to center the map so the polygon fits nicely on the screen.

```
var FT_TableID = '1wZ5CUvoqmpYOjtcnUkMvFu1hWbPeKdaMT0NkTw_5'; 
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.7200, -1.8800),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

 // GET DATA    
        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: 'Geometry',
                from: FT_TableID
            },
            options: {
                styleId: 2,
                templateId: 2
            }
        });
        //SET MAP    
        layer.setMap(map);
```

The Geometry column in the Fusion Table is the KML plot for each Polygon so it looks a bit like:

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-2.817673,50.719771,0.0 -2.816075,50.719314,0.0 -2.813323,50.718085,....
```

Comment: Which polygon do you want to fill the map?  What event?  When the map first opens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [geoxml3](http://geoxml3.googlecode.com) to parse the KML retrieved from the FusionTable using the [visualization library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/visualization) to query it.

[proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_SO_FusionTables_zoom2polygon.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']
  });
  var map;
  var layer;
  var FT_TableID = '1wZ5CUvoqmpYOjtcnUkMvFu1hWbPeKdaMT0NkTw_5';

  function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.7200, -1.8800),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTyp8Id: 'roadmap'
    });

    // GET DATA    
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: FT_TableID
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      }
    });
    //SET MAP    
    layer.setMap(map);
  }

  function changeMap(option) {
    var searchString = document.getElementById('searchString').value.replace("'", "\\'");
    var searchString = geoXML3.nodeValue(option.selectedOptions[0]);
    if (searchString == "--ALL--") {
      layer.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: 'geometry',
          from: tableid
        }
      });
      map.setZoom(8);
      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(50.7200, -1.8800));
      return;
    }
    var query = "SELECT 'geometry' FROM " + FT_TableID + " WHERE 'name' = '" + searchString + "'";
    layer.setOptions({
      query: {
        from: FT_TableID,
        select: 'geometry',
        where: "'name' = '" + searchString + "'"
      }
    });
    zoom2query(query);
  }

  function zoom2query(query) {
    // zoom and center map on query results
    //set the query using the parameter
    var queryText = encodeURIComponent(query);
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryText);
    //set the callback function
    query.send(zoomTo);
  }

  function zoomTo(response) {
    if (!response) {
      alert('no response');
      return;
    }
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
    }
    FTresponse = response;
    //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
    //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
    numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
    numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
    // handle multiple matches
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      var kml = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0);
      // create a geoXml3 parser for the click handlers
      var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map,
        zoom: false
      });

      geoXml.parseKmlString("<Placemark>" + kml + "</Placemark>");
      // handle all possible kml placmarks
      if (geoXml.docs[0].gpolylines.length > 0) {
        geoXml.docs[0].gpolylines[0].setMap(null);
        if (i == 0) var bounds = geoXml.docs[0].gpolylines[0].bounds;
        else bounds.union(geoXml.docs[0].gpolylines[0].bounds);
      } else if (geoXml.docs[0].markers.length > 0) {
        geoXml.docs[0].markers[0].setMap(null);
        if (i == 0) bounds.extend(geoXml.docs[0].markers[0].getPosition());
        else bounds.extend(geoXml.docs[0].markers[0].getPosition());
      } else if (geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons.length > 0) {
        geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].setMap(null);
        if (i == 0) var bounds = geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].bounds;
        else bounds.union(geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].bounds);
      }
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 98%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <label>NPT</label>
  <select id="searchString" onchange="changeMap(this);">
    <option value="">--ALL--</option>
    <option value="1">Beaminster NPT</option>
    <option value="2">Bearwood NPT</option>
    <option value="3">Blandford Rural NPT</option>
    <option value="4">Blandford Town</option>
    <option value="5">Bournemouth Central NPT</option>
    <option value="6">Bridport Town NPT</option>
    <option value="7">Broadstone &amp; Merley NPT</option>
    <option value="8">Canford Heath NPT</option>
    <option value="9">Central Christchurch NPT</option>
    <option value="10">Charminster &amp; Queens Park NPT</option>
    <option value="11">Chickerell NPT</option>
    <option value="12">Christchurch Town Center NPT</option>
    <option value="13">Corfe Mullen &amp; Stour NPT</option>
    <option value="14">Creekmoor NPT</option>
    <option value="15">Dorchester East Rural NPT</option>
    <option value="16">Dorchester South NPT</option>
    <option value="17">Dorchester West Rural NPT</option>
    <option value="18">East Cliff, Springborne &amp; Boscombe NPT</option>
    <option value="19">East Dorset Rural NPT</option>
    <option value="20">Ferndown Central NPT</option>
    <option value="21">Gillingham Rural NPT</option>
    <option value="22">Gillingham Town NPT</option>
    <option value="23">Hamworthy NPT</option>
    <option value="24">Heatherlands &amp; Ferndown Links NPT</option>
    <option value="25">Kinson North NPT</option>
    <option value="26">Littlemoor NPT</option>
    <option value="27">Lyme Regis NPT</option>
    <option value="28">Melcombe Regis NPT</option>
    <option value="29">Meyrick &amp; Talbot NPT</option>
    <option value="30">Moordown NPT</option>
    <option value="31">Mudeford &amp; Highcliffe NPT</option>
    <option value="32">Newtown &amp; Branksome NPT</option>
    <option value="33">Northbourne &amp; Wallisdown NPT</option>
    <option value="34">Nothe &amp; Chapelhay NPT</option>
    <option value="35">Parkstone, Penn Hill &amp; Canford Cliffs NPT</option>
    <option value="36">Poole Town &amp; Oakdale NPT</option>
    <option value="37">Portland NPT</option>
    <option value="38">Potterne &amp; Three Legged Cross NPT</option>
    <option value="39">Rossmore &amp; Alderney NPT</option>
    <option value="40">Shaftesbury Rural NPT</option>
    <option value="41">Shaftesbury Town NPT</option>
    <option value="42">Sherborne Rural NPT</option>
    <option value="43">Sherborne Town NPT</option>
    <option value="44">Southbourne, Pokesdown &amp; Littledown NPT</option>
    <option value="45">Stour Valley NPT</option>
    <option value="46">Strouden Park NPT</option>
    <option value="47">Sturminster Newton NPT</option>
    <option value="48">Swanage NPT</option>
    <option value="49">The Grange NPT</option>
    <option value="50">Throop &amp; Muscliff NPT</option>
    <option value="51">Townsend NPT</option>
    <option value="52">Verwood Town NPT</option>
    <option value="53">Wareham North NPT</option>
    <option value="54">Wareham West Rural NPT</option>
    <option value="55">West Christchurch NPT</option>
    <option value="56">West Howe NPT</option>
    <option value="57">West Moors, St Leonards &amp; St Ives NPT</option>
    <option value="58">Westbourne &amp; West Cliff NPT</option>
    <option value="59">Westham NPT</option>
    <option value="60">Weymouth Valey, Radipole &amp; Preston NPT</option>
    <option value="61">Wimborne &amp; Colehill NPT</option>
    <option value="62">Winton NPT</option>
    <option value="63">Wyke Regis NPT</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```